# Log Scale Problem

Tags: logarithms

I have a logarithmic scale of 0.3,1,4,20,110 which relates to 1,2,3,4,5  respectively. Now, I want to find out as to where the value 25 would lie on the scale above? And also, going the other way round, how would I find out as to what the value for 2.3 interpret to on the scale. Would be great if someone can help me with the answer and explanation for this.

Answer (score 0):

Your scale seems quite weird, since the quotient between two marks are not equal :P This has nothing to do with solving your problem though.

For a log scale, (e.g. 2,6,18,54...), finding where the number is (like, where $c$ lies in $[a,b]$)is the same as solving $\frac{\text{ln}c-\text{ln}a}{\text{ln}b-\text{ln}a}$, which can be evaluated by calculators, by looking up a logarithm function table, or by approximating it using all sorts of approximation methods (e.g. Newton's method, Taylor expansion).

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Thanks for the comment! But I am still stuck with it..it gives me an approximate value but not exact..one of the comments that I got is that it might be a log scale^2..Would that help?

Comment: Do you mean getting the exact point by using pure geometrical approach? I'm sorry but only very limited points can be done this way...